# using IF statement with update clause in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I want to add a condition in update I am really not sure how to do it.
I want to do following:

```
UPDATE 
    xyz_table
SET
    cap = some_text, IF (some_text IS NULL) THEN some_text = alternate_text ENDIF
WHERE
    alternate_text <> '' AND 
    cap IS NULL AND 
    some_relation_id IN ( 50, 51, 52  );
```

If there is really any way to do this, please suggest else I think I will need to execute same query twice to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` or `coalesce()`.  This is the `set` statement:

```
SET cap = some_text, 
    some_text = COALESCE(some_text, alternate_text)
```

Comment: in your case I think same performance - `coalesce` will be more performant with more arguments I believe. As it should stop evalueting arguments after first not null value, while case should do all them.

Answer (score 0):

that should do:

```
UPDATE 
    xyz_table
SET
    cap = some_text, some_text = (case when some_text IS NULL THEN alternate_text else some_text end)
WHERE
    alternate_text <> '' AND 
    cap IS NULL AND 
    some_relation_id IN ( 50, 51, 52  );
```

dont forget to `BEGIN` transaction before running

Comment: brackets are logical (optional) - no need for machine, only for eyes of human

Comment: ah and do it in transaction of course :) - I had no place to try it

Comment: `coalesce` is more elegant (And I think better) way. I just "translated" your `IF` to working `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, the simplest way would be using IsNull().

```
UPDATE 
xyz_table
SET cap = ISNULL(some_text, alternate_text)
WHERE  alternate_text <> '' AND 
cap IS NULL AND 
some_relation_id IN ( 50, 51, 52  );
```

for other conditions, I tend to use a case statement.

```
UPDATE 
xyz_table
SET cap = CASE WHEN some_text = '' THEN alternate_text ELSE some_text END
WHERE  alternate_text <> '' AND 
cap IS NULL AND 
some_relation_id IN ( 50, 51, 52  );
```